# how to get a reference to the defining 'class' inside an inner method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code:

```
var Item = function ()
{
    this.property = '';
    this.myfunction = function ()
    {
        var value = this.property;
    };

};
```

however, `this` does not point to the defining class so value doesn't get anything.

how do I access `this.property` from inside my function?

Comment: Are you calling `Item` as a constructor - `new Item()`, or as a regular function - `Item()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a closure which captures the value of parent scope's `this`:

```
var Item = function ()
{
    this.property = '';
    var self = this;
    this.myfunction = function ()
    {
        var value = self.property;
    };

};
```

**Update:** As others have pointed out, this closure is not needed when `Item` is used as a constructor (`new Item()`). Noting it here for future reference.

Comment: lol, i tried to accept the answer, and this is the first time ever i got this message: "you can accept an answer in 11 minutes". that was too quick for SO i guess.. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah they have these timers tp avoid spam I guess. You can't comment very frequently, nor can you vote too frequently too.

Comment: @Mrchief If `Item` is a constructor, that `self` variable isn't necessary. OP's code works as it is.

Comment: Yup! I'll add that to answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

just create an alias for `this`. It will get closure'd.

```
var Item = function ()
{
    this.property = '';
    var self = this;
    this.myfunction = function ()
    {
        var value = self.property;
    };

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is if you call `Item()` as a constructor.

```
var item = new Item();
item.property = "the property";
item.myfunction(); // value = "the property"
```

Comment: I am using it as a constructor, but it still doesn't work like you suggest. I'm guessing it's b/c my code is actually a bit more complicated - I'm using knockoutjs, and the binding is calling my functions. but in any case, the aliasing works.

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes depending on the context. The context being how a function was invoked, not how it was defined, but how it was called.

Besides that, you seem to be mixing up two patterns here. I'm sure you meant something like:

```
var Item = function() {
  this.property = '';
};

Item.prototype.myfunction = function() {
  var value = this.property;
};
```

Instead you kind of mixed a closure pattern with prototypal, which doesn't seem very useful there. Closure is good for hiding members, allowing for true private members, but here you're exposing the property anyway. There's no reason not to stick that function on the prototype.

Do yourself a favor and ignore any concepts you have of more traditional OO, they won't do you any good here. Prototypal isn't nearly the same thing.